# Problems with creating XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am supposed to create an XSD schema for an XML document. I was following examples from the lecture but, when I tried to use online validator, I got a lot of "src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'TypeSource' to a(n) 'simpleType definition' component." errors and the like. I've tried to search the Internet, but so far I got nothing. If anyone could help me, I'd really appreciate it:

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stephen_king_books>
<personal_data>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <surname>XYZ</surname>
    <gender>Mężczyzna</gender>
    <age birth_month="January">19</age>
    <town hometown="Bielsko-Biała">XYZ</town>
    <nationality>XYZ</nationality>
    <field_of_study>Informatyka Stosowana</field_of_study>
    <term>1</term>
    <dean_group album_number="199926">XYZ</dean_group>
</personal_data>
<copyright xmlns:xsd="http://www.uek.krakow.pl/">Wydział Zarządzania, Uniwersytet Ekonomiczny, Kraków</copyright>
<books>

    <book>
        <name>Carrie</name>
        <year>1974</year>
        <genre>Horror, Fantasy, Drama</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$7.19</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.91/5</rating>
    </book> 

    <book>
        <name>Desperation</name>
        <year>1997</year>
        <genre>Psychological, Horror, Thriller</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$8.99</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.80/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Doctor Sleep</name>
        <year>2013</year>
        <genre>Horror, Fantasy, Thriller</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$7.48</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">4.10/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Dolores Claibone</name>
        <year>1992</year>
        <genre>Thriller, Mystery, Drama</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$7.64</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.79/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Firestarter</name>
        <year>1981</year>
        <genre>Horror, Science Fiction, Thriller</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$7.19</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.83/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Just After Sunset</name>
        <year>2008</year>
        <genre>Horror, Short Stories, Fiction</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$8.09</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.84/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Shawshank Redemption</name>
        <year>1982</year>
        <genre>Fiction, Short Stories, Drama</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$8.64</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">4.51/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>Pet Sematary</name>
        <year>1983</year>
        <genre>Thriller, Horror, Mystery</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$8.09</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.89/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>The Mist</name>
        <year>1980</year>
        <genre>Horror, Science Fiction, Fantasy</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$6.01</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">3.90/5</rating>
    </book>

    <book>
        <name>The Shining</name>
        <year>1980</year>
        <genre>Horror, Thriller, Mystery</genre>
        <price currency="USD" source="https://www.amazon.com/">$5.39</price>
        <rating source="https://www.goodreads.com/">4.15/5</rating>
    </book>
</books>
```

XSD Schema:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
                                            <!--XYZ -->


    <xsd:element name="stephen_king_books">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="personal_data" type="PersonalType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="books" type="BooksType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="book" type="BookType" minOccurs="10" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="BooksType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>  


    <xsd:complexType name="AgeType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:attribute name="birth_month"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="PersonalType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="gender" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="age" type="AgeType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="town" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="nationality" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="field_of_study" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="term" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element name="dean_group" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
                </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="birth_month" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:attribute name="hometown" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:attribute name="album_number" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>   
</xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="BookType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="rating" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="source" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="from" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: You have used `TypeSource` without defining it.  The error clearly tells you that.  You should not be surprised to hear that resolution of your problem requires that you define `TypeSource`.

Comment: And how should I define it? I'm sorry, I know it's noob-like question but I have very little knowledge of this. I had one "good" file to use as an example, but it was really simple with just 1 element so I got lost

Comment: That's so basic that you're expected to try yourself and only ask if you encounter a specific problem.  Any less amounts to a "do my work for me" request.

Comment: It's the first xsd document I have ever done. Add to the fact english isn't my native language and I find it difficult to do anything on my own. What I pasted here is 100% my own work. I was hoping I'd get a hint and, fair enough, I got something. I'll try your advice.